# Замена метода load() на get()

Tags: jquery

В Qjuery3 и выше отказались от метода load(), хотя он довольно хорош был. Теперь пытаюсь использовать get() для таких же целей, чтобы вытащить определенный div. Но как я понял, он вытаскивает только по индексу из набора? Или можно как то ещё?

С load():

```
$('#indexHtml1').load('equipment.html #wb_equipmentLayoutGrid1');
```

С get():

```
$.get("equipment.html", (data) => $('#indexHtml1').html($(data).get(17)));
```

Comment: откуда мнение, что _В Qjuery3 и выше отказались от метода load()_?

Comment: Тут вроде как https://api.jquery.com/load/#load-url-data-complete

Comment: там про другой [`load`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) идет речь, то есть раньше было два метода с одним именем: один загружал Html, второй добавлял обработчик события `load`, вот этот второй как раз и убрали.

Comment: Вот в чем дело))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), как и [`get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) - это обертки над вызовом [`ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Единственная разница в том, что в случае `load` результат разбирался как `html` и осуществлялся поиск в полученном `html`, с помощью метода [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

Если посмотреть [исходники](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.3.1/src/ajax/load.js#L59), можно увидеть следующий код:

```
jQuery( "<div>" ).append( jQuery.parseHTML( responseText ) ).find( selector )
```

---

Никто не мешает использовать его в своей реализации:

```
$.get("equipment.html", (data) => $('#indexHtml1').html(
    jQuery( "<div>" ).append( jQuery.parseHTML( data ) ).find( selector )
));
```

`selector` в данном случае - `#wb_equipmentLayoutGrid1`